# How can I fix 'arr is not declared in scope' in my function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

If I run this code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int hourGlass(int x, int y) {
    int sum;
    for (int a=y; a<=y+2; a++) {
        sum += arr[x][a];
        sum += arr[x+2][a];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    
    int arr[7][7];
    
    for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<=5; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<=3; j++) {
            cout << hourGlass(i,j);
        }
    }
    
}
```

It gives the error `'arr' was not declare on this scope`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `std::array` instead of a raw array, and add it as a parameter to `hourGlass`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) as well as [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Also please invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), or take a few classes.

Comment: Named variables, including arrays, only exist in the context where they are declared.  A declaration in one function is not magically visible in another.   You are expecting `arr`, an array defined in `main()` to be visible in the function `hourGlass()`.   It isn't.   Try reading any introductory text on C++ if you want to understand this.

Comment: `sum` is used uninitialized so you will have undefined behavior when you get the code to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Your `hourGlass` function does not have access to `arr` which is in the scope of the `main` function. You can pass `arr` as a parameter to the function like this:

```
int hourGlass(int x, int y, int const (&arr)[7][7]) {
  // ...
}
```

and call the function like this:

```
hourGlass(i, j, arr)
```

Also, note that `sum` is uninitialized in your function, so reading from it invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score -4):

Simply move `int arr[7][7]` outside of the `main()` function and put it before `int hourGlass(int x, int y)`. This will make it global, that is, visible to all functions declared after it (not just a single function).

Or, perhaps a better solution (but limited to C++), use some STL container, such as `std::vector` or `std::array`, and pass it as a function argument.

Comment: Bad advice. Global variables should be shunned.